# How to set a String value in the spinner without ArrayList in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Users location is already saved in database. Here, Im retrieving state and city from database, then saved in strings. That is ok. Now, how can I set state string value in a spinner and then city string value in a 2nd spinner?

```
String state = "prov"; 
String city = "cityy";
```

When I try

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptersta = new ArrayAdapter<String>(uploadpostj.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Collections.singletonList(state)); 
spinnerstate.setAdapter(adaptersta);
```

and

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptercityy = new ArrayAdapter<String>(uploadpostj.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Collections.singletonList(city)); 
spinnercity.setAdapter(adaptercityy);
```

Then if I just try to set only city value, then it's ok, or try to set only state value, again ok. However, when I try to set both values, then only state value is set and city is empty. How can I set both string values in both spinners?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After state is selected by user, you should add cities of that state to arraylist of that state and show it in city spinner.

Comment: thanks for your answer bro, now every thing is done and my problem is how can i set his state and city on the spinners? he is uploading a post and i wanna set his state and city on the spinners, these values got from his profile using firebase database.

Comment: First try to add items to spinners manually. I mean add items from Firebase yourself. You will show all the states to user and when he/she chooses one of them, you will read Firebase and add cities of that state to the city spinner. @mwaqas

Comment: infact, my program is working fine, according to index of spinner state the spinner city shows all cities inside that arraylist. both are working properly. i just try to show his original location that is already saved on his account profile. i have got his state and city from firebase and saved in strings. now for the users ease, i wanna set his state on the spinner state and his city on the spinner city. can you make your answer easy please

Comment: You mean you want to put spinner in a special selection? @mwaqas

Comment: i have all the arraylists and i am using these lists but at the time of uploading a post the user can see his account location in the spinners. account locations(state and city) are not the arraylist. these got from his account record and saved in string. and i try to set this string value in he spinner.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with:"but when i try to set both values then only state value set and city is empty" @mwaqas

Comment: i attatched a pic, province is a state spinner, and below is a city spinner. these are two different.

Comment: i mean, when i try to set state string value in the state spinner and also try to set city string value in the city spinner. then just spinner state show the value and spinner city still not showing the value.

Comment: If city spinner doesn't depend to state spinner, do the same thing that you have done for state spinner@mwaqas

Comment: yes if city spinner doesn't depend to state then everything going good.

Comment: Can't you make them independent? @mwaqas

Comment: oo my bad. i solved my problem. i have a mistake now i am ok. thanks alot bro for your last responce.

Comment: i have declared inside onCreate() spinnerstate.setOnItemSelectedListener(uploadpostj.this);
now i have put it inside the spinnerstate.setOnTouchListener  now everything is going good